# jsTree functions are lost when I call jquery.load

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have a jsTree loaded. When I click nodes a DIV element is updated with new data. But, if I load a second DIV with:

```
$("#el").load('example.com/content.asp?n=' + nid);
```

Subsequently, any click on a node results in a:

```
Uncaught TypeError $(...).jstree is not a function.
```

Why does this happen and how can I correct this?

OK, some more code...

HTML snippet

```
__ <div id="historyPopUp">
__ <div id="popupClose" class="popupClose">X</div>
__ <div id="el" class="content"></div>
__ </div>
```

Javascript snippet

```
__ $("#el").load('example.com/content.asp?n=' + nid);
__ $("#historyPopUp").show();
```

If I remove the load() I don't get the error.
If I remove the show() I stll get the error.

Also, if I do:
    console.log(jquery.jstree);

I get a nice lot of javascript - until I do the load at which point it just outputs undefined.

Hence I think somehow jstree is being unloaded from the DOM...?

Comment: You need to show your code for us to have a chance to figure this out.

Comment: Maybe the content you're loading is redefining `$`, so you need to use `jQuery.noConflict`.